# Developing from Windows 7 box

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio on my desktop (Windows 7 Enterprise). What is the bare minimum I need to install in order to make sure I can reference SharePoint objects?

Following is my justification.

http://www.bizsupportonline.net/browserforms/how-to-use-sharepoint-object-model-submit-data-infopath-browser-form-sharepoint-list.htm

Comment: Hey anyone? so is not possible to develop web part or customized infopath form (where I have to add sharepoint reference) in non sharepoint server?

Comment: did you read the [MS's documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx)? Everything is described

Comment: and customized infopath form can be customized without sharepoint on the box.

Comment: Official Setup via MS: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8871.sharepoint-2010-how-to-set-up-a-development-environment-en-us.aspx  Third part refrences on just copying the DLL's: http://www.techerator.com/2011/02/how-to-perform-sharepoint-development-on-a-client-workstation/  - Many more available from a generic search on Google or Bing.

Comment: @JesusShelby: Hey I was looking for what you have posted. Just copying the dll and maintain the folder structure. Hope it will solve my issue. Can you post your suggestion as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Setting Up the Development Environment for SharePoint 2010 on Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx) for complete instructions on requirements and what you need to install

Comment: 1)It is incorrect and exaggerated 2)This is just straight impossible for development against Sharepoint Online (Office 365)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rob's link, I would like to mention that installing SharePoint 2010 on Windows 7 is only recommended for development. It it not recommended/supported for deployment or hosting production.

Although it is possible to do SharePoint development on Windows 7 , I like to have the development environment as close to the production environment as possible to avoid any deployment issues. Depending on how much RAM you have (>=8GB) , you could setup a Windows Server 2008 box on VirtualBox / Hyper-V and install SharePoint 2010 on that.

Comment: or simply boot on VHD (he's using Windows 7 Entreprise) and unleash the full power of his station. Had to argue months in a large entreprise to explain how silly it was to do development in Windows 7...

Comment: @Vardhaman Deshpande, in order "to have the development environment as close to the production environment" it is not necessary to develop on server. Develop on client machine deploying/run solutions onto server. It is standard approach in development.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Microsoft had been caught-22 by unmisunderstandings between Sharepoint's server and client tools/services developers and technical writers that resulted in misleading and incorrect documentation describing the necessary minimum for developing for Sharepoint development environment. That is, telling that development has to be on 64-bit machine and on server.
Except that it is incorrect, it is simply impossible for developing against Sharepoint Online (Office 365) where it is impossible to administer server or develop on it.

Developing on server is also senseless for me from many points which I believe a well-established approach and question.

**I develop on Windows XP SP3 32 bit (x86) on 32 bit machine** using Infopath Designer 2010 (32 bit) and Sharepoint Designer 2010 deploying to Sharepoint Online (Office 365), E3 (Enterprise) Plan already 3d month. Note that Windows XP or development on 32-bit machines are not even mentioned in Microsoft documentation.

I do not know any other way to use Infopath web part besides already having Infopath form already all ready and designed/"developed" in Infopath Designer. And it is irrelevant in 32 bit or 64 bit since Infopath forms or webparts, as well as solutions developed in Sharepoint Designer 2010 or Infopath Designer 2010 are not compiled on client development machine for its use on Sharepoint Server 2010 64 bit, they are being compiled dynamically on server for both 32-bit and 64-bit clients cross-platform.

Also, note that Infopath Designer 2010 use VSTA (Visual Studio Tools for Applications) for custom coding which, if you look into Help>About, is no more than truncated Visual Studio  Studio 2005 with .NET 2.0 (C# 2.0/2005 and VB.NET 2.0/2005).